# More efficient way to plot x-axis points?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graph, dry, median

I have been working on a project that requires a bar graph to be populated with price results. The chart displays the number of items within a given price range. For instance, if on amazon there are 9 items within the price range of $0-$10 the x-axis would display $0-$10 and the y-axis would be populated with a value of 9.

My bar graph has 8 bars, all with similar price ranges. $0-$10, $10-$20, $20-$30... etc.

My question is this: **What is the best way to define those individual points?** There is no common price range between these items, so the **x-axis cannot be static numbers. They must be dynamically calculated within the range of results.**

As such, currently **I am creating the x-axis points as follows:**

**I take the lowest result:**
 `@numbers[0] = results[0];`

**And I take the highest result:**
 `@numbers[8] = results[-1];`

**Then I find the median of the two:**
@numbers[4] = (@numbers[0]+@numbers[8])/2;

**I then repeat the process 6 more times**

@numbers[2] = (@numbers[0]+@numbers[4])/2; @numbers[6] = (@numbers[4]+@numbers[8])/2; @numbers[1] = (@numbers[0]+@numbers[2])/2; @numbers[3] = (@numbers[2]+@numbers[4])/2; @numbers[5] = (@numbers[4]+@numbers[6])/2; @numbers[7] = (@numbers[6]+@numbers[8])/2;

This gives me the results I need, but it seems awfully repetitive and I would imagine there is a better way.

I tried creating a loop, but I could not write it in a less verbose manner.

Is there a quicker way to do this, or perhaps something more along the lines of DRY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your bins always of equal size?  In your example, all share range=10.  If so, then you could do:

```
binspacing = overall range / (numberofbins-1);
```

and the position of bin n would be the x-axis position of numbers[0] plus n times the binspacing.

Comment: Perhaps my way would have been superior if the goal was to write as convoluted code as possible.... Thanks.

Comment: does this mean that my answer serves your purpose?